# Which version of Java should I use for Minecraft?

Tags: java, minecraft

What version of java do I need for minecraft and how would I install it I've been to multiple forums but can't figure it out.

Comment: If you experience character movement stuck issues time to time, then its a Java 7 bug and you need to downgrade to Java 6 to "fix" that issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install OpenJDK by pressing [this link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openjdk-7-jre). After, open Minecraft with right-click in Minecraft.jar > Open with > OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime.

If it's still not working, press [this link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openjdk-6-jre), and do the same as before.

Answer (score 2):

I am running minecraft on 12.04 by following these steps:

*A*. Open a terminal, and enter

`sudo apt-get purge openjdk*`

This is a "housekeeping" step that may or may not apply to your setup.

*B*. Install OpenJDK6 or OpenJDK7 from the Ubuntu Software Center.

*C.* I prefer following the instructions to install minecraft found at http://debianhelp.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/how-to-install-minecraft-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/.

It neatly integrates launching the game into Unity, and it opens like any other application (so no right-clicking to run the file). Only follow the last two steps in the tutorial ("Download and untar installation bash script" and "To install Minecraft Client").

*D.* After installing everything, I would recommended you update the LWJGL files using the link and instructions found at http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Update_LWJGL (essentially what Minecraft uses for graphics, sound, and input).

This update should prevent some common issues that bugged me (i.e., sound cutting out while running the game). CAUTION: be sure to back up the files you're updating with the new LWJGL files, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Download OpenJDK instead of Java, works better on Ubuntu and it's Open Source with better Linux support. You can download and Install it from Ubuntu Software Centre. Open JDK 6 and 7 are available, 7 is newer, I recommend you install this.
Then In minecraft.jar properties, select Open With OpenJDK 7 Runtime